# Merge columns with the same name - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I'm having a quick problem where I want to merge the two columns into just one. The two columns are actually the same but with different names
[image]

Comment: What is the data structure you are using? pandas dataframe, list or set?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `Pandas` and Assuming the `Type` of the values in the columns are not strings, You can try this:

```
df.fillna(0, inplace=True) #this will fill the NaN values with 0. This is required for the next step
df['column1'] = df['column1'] + df['column1_A'] #Add the 2 columns
```

If there is a value in the 1st column and the value in the 2nd column is NaN, the resulting value is the value of the column that has the value.

If however, both columns have values, then their values will be added.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a dataframe, you can use `combine_first` or `fillna`:

```
column1 = df['column1'].combine_first(df['column1_A'])
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
```

Documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html

or

```
column1 = df['column1'].fillna(df['column1_A'])
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
```

Documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html